# Attaching DataTriggers at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, styles, datatrigger

Is it possible to attach datatriggers to a style at runtime?  I've been through my (non-working) code a few times  now and can't seem to find where I've gone wrong.

Here's the method I use to attach the style and trigger:

```
private void AttachVisibilityTrigger(Control ctrl)
{
    Style stl = new System.Windows.Style();
    DataTrigger dt = new DataTrigger();
    PropertyInfo pi = _entity.GetType().GetProperty(this.SecondaryOptions[ctrl.Name]);
    Type controlType = this.GetControlTypeForProperty(ref dt, pi); //gets the control type based on the property name and then sets the value for the DataTrigger for which I want the visibility to be hidden
    Binding b = this.GetVisibilityBindingByControlType(controlType); //returns a new Binding with the appropriate Path set that corresponds to the bound property value (e.g IsChecked for CheckBoxes, Text for TextBoxes, SelectedValue for Comboboxes, etc)

    b.ElementName = this.SecondaryOptions[ctrl.Name];
    dt.Binding = b;
    dt.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.VisibilityProperty, System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden));

    stl.Triggers.Add(dt);
    ctrl.Style = stl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is there no way to do it with data-templating? Also: Did you step through it with the debugger, does the reflection work out, does the created binding make sense?

Comment: I need this because I have a single window which handles the creation of all new objects in my project.  The controls on the window are generated at runtime based on the datatypes of the properties for each object.  I've now been given a requirement to prevent the entry of some values until other values have first be provided.  For example, "Was property damaged?  If so, describe".  So I have a checkbox for the boolean IsDamaged property and, if checked, I want the textbox that bound to the DamageDescription property to now be visible.

Comment: "a single window which handles the creation of all new objects" that sounds quite weird. Anyway, as i noted before, can you confirm that the binding creation works out? Because the rest does seem alright to me and i do not know what objects and fields you use there.

Comment: The reflection checks out in the debugger (at least I think it does).  All the objects I instanciate and all the set properties seem to be in order.  At runtime, I check the checkbox and nothing happens though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the binding is just broken, i created similar styles in code and they work.

Especially this line looks quite suspicious:

```
b.ElementName = this.SecondaryOptions[ctrl.Name];
```

(*If you want to bind to the control itself use RelativeSource instead.*)

Have you checked the Output window of VisualStudio for binding errors?